# Uploading large files in JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, large-files

I want to upload a file that is >16GB. How can I do this in JSF?

Answer (score 3):

When using HTTP, you'll face two limitations. The one on the client side (webbrowser) and the one on the server side (webserver). The average webbrowser (IE/FF/Chrome/etc) has a limit of 2~4GB, depending on the make/version/platform. You cannot control this from the server side on. The enduser has to change the browser settings itself (sometimes this isn't possible at all). The average webserver (Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish/etc) in turn has a limit of 2GB. You can configure this, but this still won't and can't remove the limitation on the webbrowser.

Your best bet is FTP. If you want to do this by a webpage, consider an [applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) which utilizes [Apache Commons Net `FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). There are [several](http://www.google.com/search?q=ftp+upload+applet) ready-to-use opensource/commercial ones by the way.

You however still need to take into account that the disk file system on the FTP server side supports that large files. FAT32 for example has a limit of 4GB per file. NTFS and several *Nix file systems, however, can go up to 16EB.